# Sporadic packet loss through RT-N65U router with cable Internet

Tags: linux, networking, router

My setup looks like this:
TM902S (EuroDOCSIS 3.0 cable modem) <-> RT-N65U router <-> several computers in LAN

The router is running [this firmware](https://code.google.com/p/rt-n56u/) with a custom traffic shaping script.

The problem is that roughly every half an hour, for a few seconds:

- when running the Windows ping on my ISPs domain then 3 consecutive pings will time out
- PingPlotter (fancy traceroute) shows that all packets after the first hop (the router) are lost, even in TCP mode
- games that use TCP connections will time out

My ISP says they don't see any errors in the modem. Could there be some timeout, timer, action that linux runs (into), dropping packets or routes or something that causes these glitches?

Comment: Try turning off your shaping script to see if that's the cause. Try going back to the original firmware, and also try an alternative like AsusWRT Merlin to see if the firmware project you're using is the cause.

Comment: Traffic shaping does not cause it (I had it disabled and the same problem occurred) but I cannot try another firmware at the moment.

Comment: I'm not sure how your cable works, but whilst your ISP says they don't see any errors, do they see frequent reconnects? You could be dropping connection for a few seconds. If you have a dynamic IP, you could test this by checking your public IP every 5 minutes or so.

Comment: Does this router have a log file you can access? There is a thousand different things that could be happening.

Comment: My ISP says that the connection by the modem is stable. If it really lost connection then it would take longer than ~5 seconds to reconnect and my ISP would also see this.

Comment: Yes I have full root access to the router. It's a pretty trimmed down version of linux however. What should I look at?

Comment: Wherever the router logs. On my RT-AC66U this is on the "System Log" tab of the web interface.

Comment: Oh yeah that's the syslog, which is clean on my router.